# How to use Power Automate to handle excel file that gets refreshed/replaced

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a SharePoint library in which I will upload an excel file periodically.

I want to read the content of the excel file, and do some processing.

I have added the 'List rows present in a table' and it is working okay initially.

However when I upload an updated excel file, the flow fails with the below error:

```
No table was found with the name '{********-****-****-****-C30E********}'.
clientRequestId: ********-****-****-****-4fbe********
serviceRequestId: ********-****-****-****-c00c********
```

How can I get around this?

The number of rows will be different each time.

Is there any other way to read the content of the excel file?

Comment: So, does the name of the Excel table change when a new file is overwriting the old one?

Comment: as per the error, the GUID of the table changes.

Comment: What could cause the GUID to change? How is the Excel file updated? Is it replaced with a totally different file that just has the same file name? A replace is not an update.

Comment: Have you tried to "Get tables" in the previous step to get the tables of that file? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use the below.  You can build a string variable of your file name and call an http request to Sharepoint to evaluate it, find the file, and return the file ID.

I use this method so a user can provide the XLSX file name at runtime as an input to a manually triggered flow.

```
"Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint"
Site address : the Sharepoint Site
Method : Get
URI : _api/v2.0/drive/root:/My Sharepoint Folder if not at the root folder/My Sharepoint File.xlsx
Headers : accept application/json
Body : {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "path": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "table": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Test if it failed .. do something else

Then you can use the ID in your

```
"List rows present in a table"
Location : The Sharepoint Site
Document Library: Documents
File : @{body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['id']}
Table : Table1
```